# checking local files for aws s3 naming compatibility

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying a sync a large set of files and folders to s3.   The aws cli keeps failing and it is because some files have names that are not compatible with s3.   Does anyone know of any quick tools that help you scan and identify what files or folders names are compatible with s3?

Comment: Can you give an example of an invalid file name? I've never had this problem and we have some strange and long names in our buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Using the convention detailed in this link - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html, stating that any alphanumeric character and the following special characters !, -, _, ., *, ', (, and ) are safe to use, I think you can just write a regular expression to check if the file contains any other characters beside the ones detailed here and notify you in case of an incompatible name.